# New to Perl - Parsing file and replacing pattern with dynamic values

Tags: perl, shell, parsing, csv

I am very new to Perl and i am currently trying to convert a bash script to perl.

My script is used to convert nmon files (AIX / Linux perf monitoring tool), it takes nmon files present in a directory, grep and redirect the specific section to a temp file, grep and redirect the associated timestamp to aother file.

Then, it parses data into a final csv file that will be indexed by a a third tool to be exploited.

**A sample NMON data looks like:**

```
    TOP,%CPU Utilisation
TOP,+PID,Time,%CPU,%Usr,%Sys,Threads,Size,ResText,ResData,CharIO,%RAM,Paging,Command,WLMclass
TOP,5165226,T0002,10.93,9.98,0.95,1,54852,4232,51220,311014,0.755,1264,PatrolAgent,Unclassified
TOP,5365876,T0002,1.48,0.81,0.67,135,85032,132,84928,38165,1.159,0,db2sysc,Unclassified
TOP,5460056,T0002,0.32,0.27,0.05,1,5060,616,4704,1719,0.072,0,db2kmchan64.v9,Unclassified
```

The field "Time" (Seen as T0002 and really called ZZZZ in NMON) is a specific NMON timestamp, the real value of this timestamp is present later (in a dedicated section) in the NMON file and looks like:

```
ZZZZ,T0001,00:09:55,01-JAN-2014
ZZZZ,T0002,00:13:55,01-JAN-2014
ZZZZ,T0003,00:17:55,01-JAN-2014
ZZZZ,T0004,00:21:55,01-JAN-2014
ZZZZ,T0005,00:25:55,01-JAN-2014
```

The NMON format is very specific and can't be exploited directly without being parsed, the timestamp has to be associated with the corresponding value. (A NMON file is almost like a concatenation of numerous different csv files with each a different format, different fileds and so on.)

**I wrote the following bash script to parse the section i'm interested in (The "TOP" section which represents top process cpu, mem, io stats per host)**

```
#!/bin/bash

# set -x

################################################################
# INFORMATION
################################################################

# nmon2csv_TOP.sh

# Convert TOP section of nmon files to csv

# CAUTION: This script is expected to be launched by the main workflow
# $DST and DST_CONVERTED_TOP are being exported by it, if not this script will exit at launch time

################################################################
# VARS
################################################################

#  Location of NMON files
NMON_DIR=${DST}

# Location of generated files
OUTPUT_DIR=${DST_CONVERTED_TOP}

# Temp files
rawdatafile=/tmp/temp_rawdata.$$.temp
timestampfile=/tmp/temp_timestamp.$$.temp

# Main Output file
finalfile=${DST_CONVERTED_TOP}/NMON_TOP_processed_at_date_`date '+%F'`.csv

###########################
# BEGIN OF WORK
###########################

# Verify exported var are not null
if [ -z ${NMON_DIR} ]; then
    echo -e "\nERROR: Var NMON_DIR is null!\n" && exit 1
elif [ -z ${OUTPUT_DIR} ]; then
    echo -e "\nERROR: Var OUTPUT_DIR is null!\n" && exit 1
fi

# Check if temp and output files already exists
if [ -s ${rawdatafile} ]; then
    rm -f ${rawdatafile}

elif [ -s ${timestampfile} ]; then
    rm -f ${timestampfile}

elif [ -s ${finalfile} ]; then
    rm -f ${finalfile}

fi

# Get current location
PWD=`pwd`

# Go to NMON files location
cd ${NMON_DIR}

# For each NMON file present:

# To restrict to only PROD env: `ls *.nmon | grep -E -i 'sp|gp|ge'`
for NMON_FILE in `ls *.nmon | grep -E -i 'sp|gp|ge'`; do

# Set Hostname identification
serialnum=`grep 'AAA,SerialNumber,' ${NMON_FILE} | awk -F, '{print $3}' OFS=, | tr [:lower:] [:upper:]`
hostname=`grep 'AAA,host,' ${NMON_FILE} | awk -F, '{print $3}' OFS=, | tr [:lower:] [:upper:]`

# Grep and redirect TOP Section
grep 'TOP' ${NMON_FILE} | grep -v 'AAA,version,TOPAS-NMON' | grep -v 'TOP,%CPU Utilisation' > ${rawdatafile}

# Grep and redirect associated timestamps (ZZZZ)
grep 'ZZZZ' ${NMON_FILE}> ${timestampfile}

# Begin of work

while IFS=, read TOP PID Time Pct_CPU Pct_Usr Pct_Sys Threads Size ResText ResData CharIO Pct_RAM Paging Command WLMclass
    do

        timestamp=`grep ${Time} ${timestampfile} | awk -F, '{print $4 " "$3}' OFS=,`
        echo ${serialnum},${hostname},${timestamp},${Time},${PID},${Pct_CPU},${Pct_Usr},${Pct_Sys},${Threads},${Size},${ResText},${ResData},${CharIO},${Pct_RAM},${Paging},${Command},${WLMclass} \
        | grep -v '+PID,%CPU,%Usr,%Sys,Threads,Size,ResText,ResData,CharIO,%RAM,Paging,Command,WLMclass' >> ${finalfile}

    done < ${rawdatafile}

    echo -e "INFO: Done for Serialnum: ${serialnum} Hostname: ${hostname}"

done

# Go back to initial location
cd ${PWD}


###########################
# END OF WORK
###########################
```

This works as wanted and generate a main csv file (you'll see in the code that i voluntary don't keep the csv header in the file) wich is a concatenation of all parsed hosts.

But, i have a very large amount of host to treat each day (around 3000 hosts), with this current code and in worst cases, it can takes a few minutes to generate data for 1 host, multiplicated per number of hosts minutes becomes easily hours...

So, this code is really not performer enough to deal with such amount of data

10 hosts represents around 200.000 lines, which represents finally around 20 MB of csv file.
That's not that much, but i think that a shell script is probably not the better choice to manage such a process...

I guess that perl shall be much better at this task (even if the shell script could probably be improved), but my knowledge in perl is (currently) very poor, this is why i ask your help... I think that code should be quite simple to do in perl but i can't get it to work as for now...

One guy used to develop a perl script to manage NMON files and convert them to sql files (to dump these data into a database), i staged it to use its feature and with the help of some shell scripts i manage the sql files to get my final csv files.

But the TOP section was not integrated into that perl script and can't be used to that without being redeveloped.

The code in question:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# Program name: nmon2mysql.pl
# Purpose - convert nmon.csv file(s) into mysql insert file
# Author - Bruce Spencer
# Disclaimer:  this provided "as is".  
# Date - March 2007
#
$nmon2mysql_ver="1.0. March 2007";

use Time::Local;


#################################################
##  Your Customizations Go Here            ##
#################################################

#  Source directory for nmon csv files
my $NMON_DIR=$ENV{DST_TMP};
my $OUTPUT_DIR=$ENV{DST_CONVERTED_CPU_ALL};


# End "Your Customizations Go Here".  
# You're on your own, if you change anything beyond this line :-)

####################################################################
#############       Main Program            ############
####################################################################

# Initialize common variables
&initialize;

# Process all "nmon" files located in the $NMON_DIR
# @nmon_files=`ls $NMON_DIR/*.nmon $NMON_DIR/*.csv`;
@nmon_files=`ls $NMON_DIR/*.nmon`;

if (@nmon_files eq 0 ) { die ("No \*.nmon or csv files found in $NMON_DIR\n"); }

@nmon_files=sort(@nmon_files);
chomp(@nmon_files);

foreach $FILENAME ( @nmon_files ) {

  @cols= split(/\//,$FILENAME);
  $BASEFILENAME= $cols[@cols-1];

  unless (open(INSERT, ">$OUTPUT_DIR/$BASEFILENAME.sql")) { 
    die("Can not open /$OUTPUT_DIR/$BASEFILENAME.sql\n"); 
  }
  print INSERT ("# nmon version: $NMONVER\n");
  print INSERT ("# AIX version: $AIXVER\n");
  print INSERT ("use nmon;\n");

  $start=time();
  @now=localtime($start);
  $now=join(":",@now[2,1,0]);
  print ("$now: Begin processing file = $FILENAME\n");

  # Parse nmon file, skip if unsuccessful
  if (( &get_nmon_data ) gt 0 ) { next; }
  $now=time();
  $now=$now-$start;
  print ("\t$now: Finished get_nmon_data\n");


  # Static variables (number of fields always the same)
  #@static_vars=("LPAR","CPU_ALL","FILE","MEM","PAGE","MEMNEW","MEMUSE","PROC");
  #@static_vars=("LPAR","CPU_ALL","FILE","MEM","PAGE","MEMNEW","MEMUSE");

  @static_vars=("CPU_ALL");

  foreach $key (@static_vars) {
     &mk_mysql_insert_static($key);;
     $now=time();
     $now=$now-$start;
     print ("\t$now: Finished $key\n");
  } # end foreach



  # Dynamic variables (variable number of fields)
  #@dynamic_vars=("DISKBSIZE","DISKBUSY","DISKREAD","DISKWRITE","DISKXFER","ESSREAD","ESSWRITE","ESSXFER","IOADAPT","NETERROR","NET","NETPACKET");

  @dynamic_vars=("");

  foreach $key (@dynamic_vars) {
    &mk_mysql_insert_variable($key);;
    $now=time();
    $now=$now-$start;
    print ("\t$now: Finished $key\n");
  }

  close(INSERT);
#  system("gzip","$FILENAME");

}
exit(0);


############################################
#############  Subroutines  ############
############################################

##################################################################
## Extract CPU_ALL data for Static fields
##################################################################
sub mk_mysql_insert_static {

my($nmon_var)=@_; 
my $table=lc($nmon_var);

my @rawdata;
my $x;
my @cols;
my $comma;
my $TS;
my $n;


  @rawdata=grep(/^$nmon_var,/, @nmon);

  if (@rawdata < 1) { return(1); }

  @rawdata=sort(@rawdata);

  @cols=split(/,/,$rawdata[0]);
  $x=join(",",@cols[2..@cols-1]);
  $x=~ s/\%/_PCT/g;
  $x=~ s/\(MB\)/_MB/g;
  $x=~ s/-/_/g;
  $x=~ s/ /_/g;
  $x=~ s/__/_/g;
  $x=~ s/,_/,/g;
  $x=~ s/_,/,/g;
  $x=~ s/^_//;
  $x=~ s/_$//;

  print INSERT (qq|insert into $table (serialnum,hostname,mode,nmonver,time,ZZZZ,$x) values\n| );

  $comma="";
  $n=@cols;
  $n=$n-1; # number of columns -1 

  for($i=1;$i<@rawdata;$i++){ 

    $TS=$UTC_START + $INTERVAL*($i);

    @cols=split(/,/,$rawdata[$i]);
    $x=join(",",@cols[2..$n]);
    $x=~ s/,,/,-1,/g; # replace missing data ",," with a ",-1,"

    print INSERT (qq|$comma("$SN","$HOSTNAME","$MODE","$NMONVER",$TS,"$DATETIME{@cols[1]}",$x)| );

    $comma=",\n";
  }
  print INSERT (qq|;\n\n|);

} # end mk_mysql_insert

##################################################################
## Extract CPU_ALL data for variable fields
##################################################################
sub mk_mysql_insert_variable {

my($nmon_var)=@_; 
my $table=lc($nmon_var);

my @rawdata;
my $x;
my $j;
my @cols;
my $comma;
my $TS;
my $n;
my @devices;


  @rawdata=grep(/^$nmon_var,/, @nmon);

  if ( @rawdata < 1) { return; }

  @rawdata=sort(@rawdata);

  $rawdata[0]=~ s/\%/_PCT/g;
  $rawdata[0]=~ s/\(/_/g;
  $rawdata[0]=~ s/\)/_/g;
  $rawdata[0]=~ s/ /_/g;
  $rawdata[0]=~ s/__/_/g;
  $rawdata[0]=~ s/,_/,/g;

  @devices=split(/,/,$rawdata[0]);
  print INSERT (qq|insert into $table (serialnum,hostname,time,ZZZZ,device,value) values\n| );

  $n=@rawdata;
  $n--; 
  for($i=1;$i<@rawdata;$i++){ 

    $TS=$UTC_START + $INTERVAL*($i);
    $rawdata[$i]=~ s/,$//;
    @cols=split(/,/,$rawdata[$i]);

      print INSERT (qq|\n("$SN","$HOSTNAME",$TS,"$DATETIME{$cols[1]}","$devices[2]",$cols[2])| );
    for($j=3;$j<@cols;$j++){
      print INSERT (qq|,\n("$SN","$HOSTNAME",$TS,"$DATETIME{$cols[1]}","$devices[$j]",$cols[$j])| );
    }
    if ($i < $n) { print INSERT (","); } 
  }
  print INSERT (qq|;\n\n|);

} # end mk_mysql_insert_variable

########################################################
### Get an nmon setting from csv file            ###
### finds first occurance of $search             ###
### Return the selected column...$return_col     ###
### Syntax:                                      ###
###     get_setting($search,$col_to_return,$separator)##
########################################################

sub get_setting {

my $i;
my $value="-1";
my ($search,$col,$separator)= @_;    # search text, $col, $separator

for ($i=0; $i<@nmon; $i++){

  if ($nmon[$i] =~ /$search/ ) {
    $value=(split(/$separator/,$nmon[$i]))[$col];
    $value =~ s/["']*//g;  #remove non alphanum characters
    return($value);
    } # end if

  } # end for

return($value);

} # end get_setting

#####################
##  Clean up       ##
#####################
sub clean_up_line {

    # remove characters not compatible with nmon variable
    # Max rrdtool variable length is 19 chars
    # Variable can not contain special characters (% - () )
    my ($x)=@_; 

    # print ("clean_up, before: $i\t$nmon[$i]\n");
    $x =~ s/\%/Pct/g;
    # $x =~ s/\W*//g;
    $x =~ s/\/s/ps/g;       # /s  - ps
    $x =~ s/\//s/g;     # / - s
    $x =~ s/\(/_/g;
    $x =~ s/\)/_/g;
    $x =~ s/ /_/g;
    $x =~ s/-/_/g;
    $x =~ s/_KBps//g;
    $x =~ s/_tps//g;
    $x =~ s/[:,]*\s*$//;
    $retval=$x; 

} # end clean up


##########################################
##  Extract headings from nmon csv file ##
##########################################
sub initialize {

%MONTH2NUMBER =  ("jan", 1, "feb",2, "mar",3, "apr",4, "may",5, "jun",6, "jul",7, "aug",8, "sep",9, "oct",10, "nov",11, "dec",12 );

@MONTH2ALPHA =  (   "junk","jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun", "jul", "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec" );

} # end initialize

# Get data from nmon file, extract specific data fields (hostname, date, ...)
sub get_nmon_data {

my $key;
my $x;
my $category;
my %toc;
my @cols;

# Read nmon file
unless (open(FILE, $FILENAME)) { return(1); }
@nmon=<FILE>;  # input entire file
close(FILE);
chomp(@nmon);

# Cleanup nmon data remove trainig commas and colons
for($i=0; $i<@nmon;$i++ ) {
    $nmon[$i] =~ s/[:,]*\s*$//;
}

# Get nmon/server settings (search string, return column, delimiter)
$AIXVER     =&get_setting("AIX",2,",");
$DATE       =&get_setting("date",2,",");
$HOSTNAME   =&get_setting("host",2,",");
$INTERVAL   =&get_setting("interval",2,","); # nmon sampling interval

$MEMORY     =&get_setting(qq|lsconf,"Good Memory Size:|,1,":");
$MODEL      =&get_setting("modelname",3,'\s+');
$NMONVER    =&get_setting("version",2,",");

$SNAPSHOTS  =&get_setting("snapshots",2,",");  # number of readings

$STARTTIME  =&get_setting("AAA,time",2,",");
($HR, $MIN)=split(/\:/,$STARTTIME);


if ($AIXVER eq "-1") {
    $SN=$HOSTNAME;  # Probably a Linux host
} else {
    $SN =&get_setting("systemid",4,",");
    $SN     =(split(/\s+/,$SN))[0]; # "systemid IBM,SN ..."
}

$TYPE       =&get_setting("^BBBP.*Type",3,",");
if ( $TYPE =~ /Shared/ ) { $TYPE="SPLPAR"; } else { $TYPE="Dedicated"; }

$MODE       =&get_setting("^BBBP.*Mode",3,",");
$MODE       =(split(/: /, $MODE))[1];
# $MODE     =~s/\"//g;


# Calculate UTC time (seconds since 1970)
# NMON V9  dd/mm/yy
# NMON V10+ dd-MMM-yyyy

if ( $DATE =~ /[a-zA-Z]/ ) {   # Alpha = assume dd-MMM-yyyy date format
    ($DAY, $MMM, $YR)=split(/\-/,$DATE);
    $MMM=lc($MMM);
    $MON=$MONTH2NUMBER{$MMM};
} else {
    ($DAY, $MON, $YR)=split(/\//,$DATE);
    $YR=$YR + 2000;
    $MMM=$MONTH2ALPHA[$MON];
} # end if

## Calculate UTC time (seconds since 1970).  Required format for the rrdtool.

##  timelocal format
##    day=1-31
##    month=0-11
##    year = x -1900  (time since 1900) (seems to work with either 2006 or 106)

$m=$MON - 1;  # jan=0, feb=2, ...

$UTC_START=timelocal(0,$MIN,$HR,$DAY,$m,$YR); 
$UTC_END=$UTC_START + $INTERVAL * $SNAPSHOTS;

@ZZZZ=grep(/^ZZZZ,/,@nmon);
for ($i=0;$i<@ZZZZ;$i++){

    @cols=split(/,/,$ZZZZ[$i]);
    ($DAY,$MON,$YR)=split(/-/,$cols[3]);
    $MON=lc($MON);
    $MON="00" . $MONTH2NUMBER{$MON};
    $MON=substr($MON,-2,2);
    $ZZZZ[$i]="$YR-$MON-$DAY $cols[2]";
    $DATETIME{$cols[1]}="$YR-$MON-$DAY $cols[2]";


} # end ZZZZ

return(0);
} # end get_nmon_data
```

It almost (i say almost because with recent NMON versions it can sometimes have some issue when no data present) does the job, and it does it much much faster that would do my shell script if i would use it for these section

This is why i think perl shall be a perfect solution.

Off course, i don't ask anyone to convert my shell script into something final in perl, but at least to give me to right direction :-)

I really thank anyone in advance for your help !

Comment: Hi, do you have a specific question? Also, you may want to reduce the code you have to a small self contained example relevant to your question.

Comment: Please have a read through http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking to find out how to ask good questions.

Comment: Ok i will reduce and be more clear in my question, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally i am strongly opposed to questions like this but our production systems are down and until they are fixed i do not really have all that much to do...

Here is some code that might get you started. Please consider it pseudo code as it is completely untested and probably won't even compile (i always forget some parantheses or semicolons and as i said, the actual machines that can run code are unreachable) but i commented a lot and hopefully you will be able to modify it to your actual needs and get it to run.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open INFILE, "<", "path/to/file.nmon";      # Open the file.

my @topLines;                               # Initialize variables.
my %timestamps;

while <INFILE>                              # This will walk over all the lines of the infile.
{                                           # Storing the current line in $_.
    chomp $_;                               # Remove newline at the end.
    if ($_ =~ m/^TOP/)                      # If the line starts with TOP...
    {
        push @topLines, $_;                 # ...store it in the array for later use.
    }
    elsif ($_ =~ m/^ZZZZ/)                  # If it is in the ZZZZ section...
    {
        my @fields = split ',', $_;         # ...split the line at commas...
        my $timestamp = join ",", $fields(2), $fields(3);   # ...join the timestamp into a string as you wish...
        $timestamps{$fields(1)} = $timestamp;               # ...and store it in the hash with the Twhatever thing as key.
    }

# This iteration could certainly be improved with more knowledge
# of how the file looks. For example the search could be cancelled
# after the ZZZZ section if the file is still long.
}

close INFILE;

open OUTFILE, ">", "path/to/output.csv";    # Open the file you want your output in.

foreach (@topLines)                         # Iterate through all elements of the array.
{                                           # Once again storing the current value in $_.
    my @fields = split ',', $_;             # Probably not necessary, depending on how output should be formated.
    my $outstring = join ',', $fields(0), $fields(1), $timestamps{$fields(2)};  # And whatever other fields you care for.
    print OUTFILE $outstring, "\n";         # Print.
}
close OUTFILE;
print "Done.\n";
```

Comment: I really thank you for the time you spent answering my question, even if i well understood it was not quite correct.

I'm working on it thanks to your code and will revert :-)

Again thanks.

Comment: Once your problem is solved and if it turns out that this or another answer helped you solve it, hitting accept on that answer would be appreciated.